# Call shared gRPC method inside same service

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-python

I have a situation where I want one gRPC method to call another gRPC method within the same service. Reason being, there are two services that rely on this one common method. What's the best way to do this?

Example:

```
class FooServicer(foo_pb2_grpc.FooServicer):
  def CommonMethod(self, request: CommonMethodRequest, context) -> CommonMethodResponse:
    ...

  def Method1(self, request: Method1Request, context) -> Method1Response:
    # do some stuff
    # <insert code to call CommonMethod>
    # do some more stuff

class BarServicer(bar_pb2_grpc.BarServicer):
  def Method2(self, request: Method2Request) -> Method2Response:
    # do some stuff
    <creates gRPC stub to FooServicer and calls CommonMethod>
    # do some more stuff
```

In FooServicer, should I call `CommonMethod` with

```
  ...
  response = self.CommonMethod(request, context) // Context passed in the same as Method1 Context
  ...
```

or should I create a gRPC stub to the same service? What's the pros and cons of each?

Answer (score 0):

If the common method is used by multiple places in the same service, probably extract it to a different place and make all 3 methods call it is a better way.

But if you want to keep it inside `FooServicer`, then you should be able to call is use `self.CommonMethod`, create a stub isn't a good thing here since it will add an extra layer to the whole flow.